# MAX-2-XOR-SAT: Why does the special case work?

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, satisfiability

I'm a new user so I cannot respond directly to [this post here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16691/min-2-xor-sat-and-max-2-xor-sat-are-they-np-hard).

I'm confused about the answers to the question, namely that **MAX-2-XOR-SAT** is in $P$ iff each clause is of the form $(x_i \oplus \neg x_j)$ (or is it $(x_i \oplus x_j)$? There were two different answers). Couldn't you make a simple substitution $\neg x_i \rightarrow y_i$ such that this is always the case, so that you can get the special case always? For example, you could convert, $(x_1 \oplus \neg x_2) \wedge (x_1 \oplus x_3)$, to $(x_1 \oplus y_2) \wedge (x_1 \oplus x_3)$.

Forgive me if there is something obvious I am missing...I'm new to this field.

Thank you!

---

**EDIT**

To clear up confusion, I'm asking if a substitution is made for *all* clauses with a matching variable. Take for example,

$$(x_1 \oplus x_2) \land (\neg x_1) \land (x_1 \oplus \neg x_3)$$

By substituting $\neg x_3 \rightarrow y_3$ we get:

$$(x_1 \oplus x_2) \land (\neg x_1) \land (x_1 \oplus y_3)$$

Where each 2-clause is of the form $(x_i \oplus x_j)$. It seems that in this case it still remains in $P$. Which raises a new question, how do single clauses affect the complexity of the solution?

Comment: Rather than editing the question to ask new questions or follow-up questions, it's probably better to post a new question via the 'Ask Question' button.  Thank you.

Comment: @D.W. thanks I've put it into a new question here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/78110/max-2-xor-sat-when-does-the-special-case-work

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't make a substitution like that.  The resulting formula isn't equivalent to the original formula.

Consider

$$(x_1 \oplus x_2) \land (x_1 \oplus \neg x_2).$$

This formula is not satisfiable.  However, if we apply your substitution, we end up with the formula

$$(x_1 \oplus x_2) \land (x_1 \oplus y_2).$$

The resulting formula now has 6 variables and is satisfiable.  For example, you can set $x_1=\text{True}$, $x_2=\text{False}$, $y_2=\text{False}$.

The problem is that your substitution doesn't ensure that $y_i = \neg x_i$, so it doesn't preserve satisfiability.  (If you wanted to preserve satisfiability, you could do that by making your substitution and then adding clauses of the form $(y_i \oplus x_i)$ ... but while that would preserve satisfiability, it wouldn't preserve the maximum number of clauses that can be simultaneously satisfied, so it still wouldn't help for solving MAX-2-XOR-SAT.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I meant to ask a more complete question.

What I'm considering is if _all_ clauses containing a variable are satisfied. For example, in your case, it would be:
$$(x_1 \oplus x_2) \land (x_1 \oplus \neg x_2).$$
Which becomes, once $\neg x_2 \rightarrow y_2$,
$$(x_1 \oplus \neg y_2) \land (x_1 \oplus y_2).$$
It seems in this case that the satisfiability is preserved.

Comment: The case that I'm interested in is more like this:
$$(x_1 \oplus x_2) \land (\neg x_1) \land (x_1 \oplus \neg x_3)$$
With the substitution, doesn't this contain only $(x_1 \oplus x_2)$ kind of cases?

Comment: @user2998891, perhaps it's worth asking a new question that is clearer about what you are asking.  For instance, I'm not sure whether you meant to ask about 2-XOR-SAT or about MAX-2-XOR-SAT.  The question you link to is about MAX-2-XOR-SAT, so if you want to know about 2-XOR-SAT, that's a fundamentally different situation.  Also, I'm not clear on what substitution you have in mind, or what property you think it has.

Comment: we are trying to understand whether a certain CNF which encode XOR relationships falls under XOR-SAT or MAX-XOR-SAT, to give you some background.

Comment: @user2998891, I don't know what you mean by "falls under".  I suggest you think about it hard, then ask a new question where you are clearer about what your question is.

Comment: Basically we mean that our problem "falls under" MAX-SAT or XOR-SAT if we can solve it as such. In our case we are mapping different interactions between variables in a CNF and it turns out all the interactions are either single clauses, XOR's, or XOR's with negations. So we hoped we could solve the CNF as an XOR-SAT because of this, but in general it could be MAX-XOR-SAT. This is why we are asking the question on MAX-XOR-SAT.

We hoped that we could clarify whether our CNF can be solved easily, ie. the problem is in $P$, but we're unsure. I've updated my question to contain examples.